# Default language doesn't work

Tags: windows-phone-7

I've added english language to my app written originally in polish, set the default language to en-us but for some reason people from non-english speaking countries still get the polish translation, any ideas?

Comment: How do you load your strings for display?

Comment: can you share your code snippet for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to modify the project file manually:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
       <SupportedCultures>en;pl</SupportedCultures>
```

You don't have to add your default language to `SupportedCultures`

Comment: so for default english and polish for polish people I should write
<SupportedCultures>en;pl</SupportedCultures> ?

Comment: sorry, I wasn't home and just wanted to know asap.
Changing to en;pl didn't help.
I have two resource files, for en-US and pl-PL. English should be default for every country which is not Poland.

Comment: if the resource file is called AppResources.pl-PL you have to put pl-PL into SupportedCultures. The default one should just be called AppResources

Comment: So that's the problem- everything in my AppResource is in polish because that's the language I've been starting with. Do I have to change it to english? Is there a workaround to only use pl-PL and en-US files?

Comment: Aporesources.resx contains the default language. If it is polish and you dont want that, open the Appresources.resx file with a text editor, and copy the content to Appresources.pl-PL.resx file.