# Windows Phone 8: Localization doesn't work

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization

I have moved my application from WP7 (where I had no problems with localization) to the WP8. Now only English language is displayed regardless phone settings. My setup is (taken from http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/localizing-a-windows-phone-app-step-by-step):

### Resource folder content

- AppResources.en-US.resx *[English]*
- AppResources.pl-PL.resx *[Polish]*
- AppResources.resx *[English]*

### WMAppManifest.xml:

```
<DefaultLanguage xmlns="" code="pl-PL" />
<Languages xmlns="">
  <Language code="en-US" />
  <Language code="pl-PL" />
</Languages>
```

### Phone settings:

[image: phone is set to poland locale]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to modify the main project file manually and add this:

```
<PropertyGroup>
        <SupportedCultures>en;pl</SupportedCultures>
```

You don't have to add your default language to SupportedCultures, see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266490/default-language-doesnt-work/20266583#20266583)