# More than 3 localizations supported on WP8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, localization

I have simple WP8 app that is translated to Dutch and German. The default is English (US). Now I've made a translation to Spanish, but the app doesn't translate when I set the phone (emulator or real phone) to Spanish.

I noticed that I can select Dutch and German as base languages, but with Spanish I can't. I need to select Spanish - Spain, or Spanish - Mexican, on the phone.

I changed the resource name from AppResource.es.resx to AppResource.es-ES.resx but it doesn't work. No Spanish translation of my app.

I've looked around, but there's nowhere any mentioning of a limited amount of languages a single app can support.

Anybody an idea as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Btw, I renamed my resource file to AppResource.fr.resx and set the phone to French, but same issue.

Iwan

Comment: Check this: [Windows Phone 8: Localization doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20925627/windows-phone-8-localization-doesnt-work)

Comment: See this too -culture codes - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202918%28v=vs.105%29.aspx