# .xap file supports multilanguage but the package details showing only two language.

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I have created a project having three language as supported language in WMAppmanifest.xaml and those culture are showing in assembly information of project. But the problem is when I am creating a package and uploading it at (dev.windowsphone.com/en-us/AppSubmission) it is showing me only two language in package detail.

Please help me out!!

Thanks

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20266490/default-language-doesnt-work/20266583#20266583

Comment: @thumbmunkeys - where should I paste this <PropertyGroup> tag as manifest file is not supporting it. WMAppManifest file already having this <Languages xmlns="">
    <Language code="gu" />
    <Language code="hi" />
    <Language code="en" />
  </Languages>

Comment: as stated in the answer, in the project file...